# Python errorbar with varied marker size

Tags: python, marker, errorbar

I used python `errorbar` to make a plot, however the arguments `markersize` can only be a scalar not an array, which means all the data points have the same marker size. I am wondering how can I assign different `markersize` to different data points?

```
ax.errorbar(x,y,xerr=[xlow,xup],yerr=[ylow,yup],color='r',ls='None',marker='o',markersize=5.)
```

If I create the marker size to be `5.0*y`, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you plot error bars and markers separately?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#create x and y values
xval = np.arange(1,10)
yval = np.square(xval)
#define error bars and markersize
yerrmi = np.abs(np.cos(xval) * xval)
yerrpl = np.abs(np.sin(xval) * xval)
yerr = np.stack([yerrpl, yerrmi])
markerpl = 5 * yval

#plot error bars
plt.errorbar(xval, yval, yerr = yerr, ls = "None", color = "r")
#plot scatter plot
plt.scatter(xval, yval, s = 5 * yval, marker = "h", color = "r")

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks~